# Fullscreen API - How to expand the element to fullscreen slowly

Tags: javascript, html5-fullscreen

I know about the [Fullscreen API](https://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen). I'm trying to make a div expand to/collapse from fullscreen slowly (say, over 2 seconds) as opposed to instantaneously. Is there an easy way to that?